# Ruby: What is the order of keys/values returned by Hash.keys and Hash.values methods?

Tags: ruby, hash, key

Is it the same order in which the items were added to the Hash ?

Comment: As you can gather by the sum of the comments below, this behavior is different between 1.8 and 1.9 versions of Ruby.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The top of [the Ruby 1.9.2 documentation for the Hash class](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html) declares:

> Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted.

Cursory tests suggest that this does indeed apply to both `Hash#keys` and `Hash#values`, although the corresponding documentation for those methods doesn't seem to specify it.

Comment: Note that this behavior was new in Ruby 1.9. Previous versions did not preserve ordering.

Answer (score 13):

In Ruby 1.8, there's no guaranteed order for the elements in a hash.