# Sort keys in Ruby hash without changing the associated values from their original positions

Tags: ruby, sorting

I'm having trouble sorting a Hash that looks like this:

```
{9=>["Blake Johnson", "Jack Bauer"], 
 7=>["Bart Simpson", "Homer Simpson"],
 10=>["Avi Flombaum", "Jeff Baird"]}
```

and I would like it to look like this:

```
{7=>["Blake Johnson", "Jack Bauer"],
 9=>["Bart Simpson", "Homer Simpson"],
 10=>["Avi Flombaum", "Jeff Baird"]}
```

Comment: So you want the keys to be ordered, but the values unchanged (therefore swapping keys)?

Comment: yes that's correct. I want to keep the same key value pair but change de order. small to large

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski good point, I didn't notice that

Comment: @Cyzanfar Must you modify it in place, or do you mind copying it to a new hash?

Comment: sorry come again, not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @Cyzanfar Is it okay if you have to create a new Hash (memory constraints), rather than modifying the original hash's order directly?

Comment: Yeah its fine to pass the sorted has to a new Hash variable. Only thing it need to look exactly like this `{7=>["Blake Johnson", "Jack Bauer"],
 9=>["Bart Simpson", "Homer Simpson"],
 10=>["Avi Flombaum", "Jeff Baird"]}`

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using? I think it's a mistake to rely on the iteration order for a `Hash`, even though in ruby 1.9+ it's somewhat predictable. I'm curious also what you mean when you say the `Hash` "looks like" that -- how are you inspecting it? Essentially what you're asking is impossible on ruby 1.8, and in later versions it might be possible to write code that would predictably do what you want but I would not regard it as correct because in theory a Hash is unordered.

Comment: You're not sorting the hash, you're reassigning the keys and values. Sorting a hash does no good so order the keys how you want and use `values_at` to retrieve the values in the order once you've reassigned the key/value pairs. A good question to ask yourself is *WHY* do you need to reassign the key/value pairs like you are? I'd suspect that your hash isn't being generated correctly, or that the data isn't being requested or parsed correctly. Also, where is your code? We need to know you've tried writing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hash = {
 9 => ["Blake Johnson", "Jack Bauer"],
 7 => ["Bart Simpson", "Homer Simpson"],
 10 => ["Avi Flombaum", "Jeff Baird"]
}

Hash[hash.sort]

 { 7=>["Bart Simpson", "Homer Simpson"], 
   9=>["Blake Johnson", "Jack Bauer"], 
  10=>["Avi Flombaum", "Jeff Baird"]
 }
```

Comment: Not sure how this answer got accepted, since it doesn't produce the required output from the original question. This solution preserves key-value pairs, whereas the sample output given by OP breaks key-value pairs.

Answer (score 5):

The requirement is quite weird, but this should work:

```
hash = {
  9 => ["Blake Johnson", "Jack Bauer"],
  7 => ["Bart Simpson", "Homer Simpson"],
  10 => ["Avi Flombaum", "Jeff Baird"]
}

hash.keys.sort.zip(hash.values).to_h
#=> {7=>["Blake Johnson", "Jack Bauer"], 9=>["Bart Simpson", "Homer Simpson"], 10=>["Avi Flombaum", "Jeff Baird"]}
```

Comment: interesting... Problem with this is that it doesn't swaps around the value contained in the nested array. I would like it to look exactly like this: `{7=>["Blake Johnson", "Jack Bauer"],
 9=>["Bart Simpson", "Homer Simpson"],
 10=>["Avi Flombaum", "Jeff Baird"]}` whereas the solution you gave me return a hash this way : `{7=>["Homer Simpson", "Bart Simpson"], 9=>["Avi Flombaum", "Jeff Baird"], 10=>["Blake Johnson", "Jack Bauer"]}`

Comment: @Cyzanfar I have no idea why you get a completely different output.

Comment: It's surely to do with the insertion order. If you create the hash this way: `hash = {}; hash[9] = "a"; hash[10] = "b"; hash[7] = "c"`, then your code would produce `{ 7 => "a", 9 => "b", 10 => "c" }`, whereas if swap the order of the last two statements you get `{ 7 => "a", 9 => "c", 10 => "b" }`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208512/ruby-what-is-the-order-of-keys-values-returned-by-hash-keys-and-hash-values-met

Comment: @gregates it sorts the keys and re-assigns the values in their original insertion order. If you change that order, you get a different result. Do I miss something?

Comment: No I agree with you, I'm just noting that if there's a difference in results it must be that the two of you constructed the original hash in different ways (or the OP is using Ruby 1.8). i.e., your solution works if you just build the example hash as a literal, but wouldn't necessarily generalize.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
sorted_hash = {}
hash.sort.each do |key_value_pair|
    key = key_value_pair[0]
    value = key_value_pair[1]
    sorted_hash[key] = value
end
```

The sort method returns a sorted arrays of arrays where each element of these inner arrays are [key, {value}] and they are sorted by the key (if it is a sortable object).